# Check with Python that webcam is being used in Chrome

Tags: windows, python-2.7, camera

If webcam is being used in Chrome or by any other application, then my script takes a image having size of 0 bytes(**which does not contain any photos**).

**My Script to take image from webcam:**

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
ret, frame = cam.read()
cv2.imwrite('my_pic.jpg', frame)
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**My question:**

1. Can I still be able to take image from webcam simultaneously when my camera is used in Camera or by any other application? If yes then how can I do it?(**It would be so grateful if there is any way of doing this**)
2. If its impossible to do question number 1 then how can I check if my camera is used in Chrome or by any other application via python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't capture image with opencv when camera is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300145/cant-capture-image-with-opencv-when-camera-is-in-use)

Comment: yeah I posted the same question because I could not get any soultion